# prove that $(xy-2,x^2-2)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Q[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I want to prove that $(xy-2,x^2-2)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Q[x,y]$.

To begin with, I constructed a map $\phi:\mathbb Q[x,y] \to \mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ by $f\mapsto f(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2)$, hoping to show that its kernel is $(xy-2,x^2-2)$.

Clearly, $\phi$ kills $(xy-2,x^2-2)$. To show the other containment. We take $f$ vanishing at $(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2)$. Here is where I get stuck. How to express $f$ as $f=u(xy-2)+v(x^2-2)$, where $u,v\in \mathbb Q[x,y]$?

Any other method will be appreciated if this one doesn't work. It would be great if there is a general method to deal with many other similar problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ideal $I$ contains $xy-2-(x^2-2)=x(y-x)$ and so also $x^2(y-x)$.
Then also it contains $x^2(y-x)-(x^2-2)(y-x)=2(y-x)$, and so $y-x$ too.

Therefore $f(x,y)\equiv f(x,x)\pmod{I}$ for any polynomial $f$ over $\Bbb Q$. If $f(\sqrt2,\sqrt2)=0$ then $g(x)=f(x,x)$ is divisible by $x^2-2$
so $g(x)\in I$. As $f(x,y)\equiv g(x)\pmod I$ then $f(x,y)\in I$ also.

Comment: This is marvellous! Just curious, where (or how) did you learn about these polynomial tricks?

Comment: @TiWen the second calculation essentially uses that $x$ is invertible modulo $I$ (obvious from $x^2-2\equiv0$), the first is essentially plugging in $x=\sqrt2$ in $xy-2=0$, but a denominator-free way to say $\frac2{\sqrt2}=\sqrt2$

Answer (score 2):

We can find $\{ x-y,x^2-2 \}$ is a minimal Grobner basis for $I=(xy-2,x^2-2)$, so $$ I=(x-y,x^2-2) $$

then $ \mathbb Q[x,y]/(x-y,x^2-2) \cong \mathbb Q[x]/(x^2-2) \cong \mathbb Q(\sqrt2)  $

Answer (score 0):

Lord Shark the Unknown's answer is very beautiful, but I also find it very clever. I thought I might post an answer which is decidedly less clever, but which uses very broadly applicable ideas.

First, note that by the third isomorphism theorem for rings, we have $\mathbb{Q}[X, Y]/\langle XY-2, X^{2}-2 \rangle \cong (\mathbb{Q}[X, Y]/\langle XY-2)/\langle \overline{X^{2}-2} \rangle$, where $\overline{X^{2}-2}$ denotes the image of $X^{2}-2$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X, Y]/\langle XY-2\rangle$. I claim that $\mathbb{Q}[X, Y]/\langle XY-2\rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}[Z, Z^{-1}] \cong S^{-1}\mathbb{Q}[Z]$, where $S = \{Z^{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset \mathbb{Q}[Z]$.

Indeed, consider the morphism of $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras $\varphi \colon \mathbb{Q}[X, Y] \to \mathbb{Q}[Z, Z^{-1}]$ which is defined on generators by $X \mapsto Z, Y \mapsto 2Z^{-1}$. Then $XY-2 \in \ker(\varphi)$, so by the universal property of the quotient, $\varphi$ descends to a well-defined morphism of $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras $\tilde{\varphi} \colon \mathbb{Q}[X, Y]/\langle XY - 2 \rangle \to \mathbb{Q}[Z, Z^{-1}]$ sending $\overline{X}$ to $Z$ and $\overline{Y}$ to $2Z^{-1}$.

On the other hand, we can define a morphism of $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras $\rho \colon \mathbb{Q}[Z] \to \mathbb{Q}[X, Y]/\langle XY - 2 \rangle$ by $Z \mapsto \overline{X}$. Since $\overline{X} \cdot \overline{\frac{1}{2}Y} = \overline{1}$, $\overline{X} \in (\mathbb{Q}[X, Y]/\langle XY - 2 \rangle)^{\times}$. In particular, by the universal property of localization, $\rho$ extends to a morphism $\tilde{\rho} \colon \mathbb{Q}[Z, Z^{-1}] \to \mathbb{Q}[X, Y]/\langle XY - 2 \rangle$ which sends $Z$ to $\overline{X}$ and $Z^{-1}$ to $\overline{\frac{1}{2}Y}$. It is straightforward to check that $\tilde{\rho} \circ \tilde{\varphi}$ and $\tilde{\varphi} \circ \tilde{\rho}$ are the identities on their respective domains; it is sufficient to check this on generators, e.g. that $(\tilde{\rho} \circ \tilde{\varphi})(\overline{X}) = \overline{X}$. Thus, via the isomorphism $\tilde{\varphi}$, we have

$$\mathbb{Q}[X, Y]/\langle XY-2, X^{2}-2 \rangle \cong (\mathbb{Q}[X, Y]/\langle XY-2)/\langle \overline{X^{2}-2} \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}[Z, Z^{-1}]/\langle Z^{2}-2\rangle$$

It remains to show that $\mathbb{Q}[Z, Z^{-1}]/\langle Z^{2}-2\rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$. There are many ways to do this, but one is the following: since taking quotients "commutes" with localization, we have $\mathbb{Q}[Z, Z^{-1}]/\langle Z^{2}-2\rangle \cong (\mathbb{Q}[Z]/\langle Z^{2}-2\rangle)_{\overline{Z}} \cong (\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}])_{\sqrt{2}} \cong \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, where the last isomorphism follows since $\sqrt{2} \in (\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}])^{\times}$.

Comment: If you aimed at a straightforward approach then why don't factorize first by $X^2-2$? This way the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)[Y]/(\sqrt 2Y-2)$ which is isomorphic to  $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$.

Comment: @user26857: that'd be fine too; this is just the approach that came naturally to me. I don't think this method is any more laborious, though - I was just very explicit with details. To each his own.